# Can we generate a sequence number during CDC from Oracle to AWS PostgreSQL using AWS DMS under transformation rule option?

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, cdc, aws-dms

I need to do a CDC from Oracle to AWS RDS PostgreSQL using AWS DMS CDC task. When a new record is inserted, I need to generate sequence ID using DMS. When update happens, I need to update the records at the target and sequence ID should remain the same. Can I achieve it under transformation rule ? Is there any option to generate a sequence Id ?